# How to make relation between two taxonomies in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have **Variations** taxonomy and each Variation taxonomy has multiple **Meta tags**.
I have created Variations taxonomy and Meta tags taxonomy. 
But the problem is I could not make the relation between two taxonomies.

**These taxonomies created on custom post type.**

How can I achieve it? Any idea or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the taxonomies below the custom post type on the admin page? If you do, then just click on Variations, and WP will let you make the relation to other entries in the taxonomy.